# LocalStorage QML return

Tags: local-storage, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have a little problem with understanding a function. Here is the code:

```
var _db
var noteItems = {}

_db.readTransaction( function(tx) {
    var rs = tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM note WHERE markerId=? ORDER BY markerid DESC", [markerId] );
    var item

    for (var i=0; i< rs.rows.length; i++) {
        item = rs.rows.item(i)
        noteItems[item.noteId] = item;
        console.log(noteItems[item.noteId].x)
    }
)}
```

The structure of the database is `markerId Int`, `x Int`, `y Int`, `noteText TEXT`.

I don't really understand what this function returns, I'm a beginner in QML. Does it return an array of objects? What is the structure of the object?

Something like this maybe:

```
noteItems {
    markerId : 0
    x: 0
    y: 0
    noteText: "example"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the function in your question is not correctly closed, you have unbalanced braces. It looks a bit like a shabby cut and and paste.

That said, assuming that you showed us the whole content of that function, you can notice that it doesn't contain any `return` statement. Because of that, such a function returns `undefined` by default.

It makes sense to behave that way, anyway. Accordingly to the [here](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/), `_db.readTransaction` accepts a callback function to which to pass a transaction object (usually it is named `tx`, but feel free to choose the name you prefer) and it doesn't care at all about the returned value, so returning `undefined` by omitting the `return` statement is a perfectly reasonable approach.

Actually, the function is filling an object named `noteItems` that lives in the outer scope and that's possible because of a concept called `closure`. It's pretty long to describe and off topic here, but we can sum up saying that within your function you can access any variable defined out of there, as far as those variables are part of an enclosing `scope`.

The way exported objects are constructed can be found in the official documentation, so I won't go further on this subject. You'll find that it's close to what you guessed.

Finally, as stated [here](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/), QML doesn't interfere with JavaScript's natural scoping, so I suggest to read more about it to fully understand what's happening. [That](http://jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html) one is a good point from which to start.